# Android - Firebase notifications not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having an issue with Firebase notifications. I set up it as the docs but it's not working. Below, you can see my code. Although I think everything is right.

Here's my `NotificationsService`

```
public class NotificationsService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String TAG = "Notification";

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
}
```

And the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.usefashion.useapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".NotificationsService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".InstanceIdService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

It would be great if anyone could help me. I have an `InstanceIdService` too but its not the part of this question.

**Edit 1:**

I realized that when I send a notification by console, this message is showed in debug:

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error resolving target intent service, skipping classname enforcement. Resolved service was: com.taplane.triviaquiz/com.msi.logocore.helpers.thirdparty.firebase.FirebaseServiceListener
```

What is it?

Comment: When you send the notification is the app in the foreground or background?

Comment: In foreground, having in mind that I'm debugging the app and looking in log if the notification was received.

Comment: If the app is in the background do you see the notification that Firebase creates for you?

Comment: Are you using the Firebase console to send the message? If so are you sure your device is in the group you are sending to?

Comment: Yes, i'm sending to segment of users that have app 'com.usefashion.useapp'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130816/discussion-between-larry-mckenzie-and-lucas-s-muller).

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie Please, see Edit 1.

Comment: Why is your service exported?

Comment: I resolved the problem doing this: removing the exported line in both services and setting `android:priority="10000"`. Thank you so much.

Comment: I do not think you should need the priority after removing "exported".

Answer (score 0):

hers's my fcm services:

=> public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdServices extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "FireBase token: " + refreshedToken);
    Prefs.setFirebaseToken(getApplicationContext(), refreshedToken);
}
```

}

=> public class MyFirebaseMessagingServices extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getData() + " Message Body");
    Map<String, String> notiMessage = remoteMessage.getData();
    String type = notiMessage.get("type");
    String title = notiMessage.get("title");
    String message = notiMessage.get("message");
    String orderId = notiMessage.get("order_id");
    sendNotification(type, title, message, orderId);
}

//This method is only generating push notification
private void sendNotification(String type, String title, String message, String orderId) {

    if (Prefs.getIsLogin(this)) {
        Intent intent = null;
        if (type.equals("order")) {
            intent = new Intent(this, OrderConfirmationActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Constant.ORDER_ID, orderId);
            intent.putExtra("FromNoti", true);
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        }


        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_marker);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

}

=> In Manifest file:

```
    <service android:name="com.labagel.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingServices">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name="com.labagel.fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIdServices">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```